# Colorkey collision between Rects in Pygame, Python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame, pygame-surface, color-key

I'm currently working on a game on Pygame, Python 3 and one of the essential parts of the game is the collision of Rects in a bullet-target situation.

This is fairly easy to achieve using the `colliderect` function but it is necessary for the pixels that are the same color as the colorkey to not be counted.

For example, if one of the sprites (the character) is in the form of a large equilateral triangle with its base being horizontal and a bullet is coming from the top-left, `colliderect` would detect the collision right away even though the pixels in the top-left are of the player's sprite are transparent.

I need to make a function that will detect to collision only when the bullet has reached pixels that are of a different color than the colorkey. This is easy enough if the bullet is only one pixel:

```
if player.get_at((bullet[0] - player.left, bullet[1] - player.top)) != player.get_colorkey():
```

I tried iterating the above statement for every pixel in the bullet, but, of course, that caused extensive lag. Is there a different, more efficient, way?

Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the collide_mask function:

http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/sprite.html#pygame.sprite.collide_mask

In brief you give each sprite a self.mask attribute (using pygame.mask.from_surface()) - which you can do using a colorkey, or per-pixel alpha.  Then you include it as a callback for the spritecollide function like so:

pygame.sprite.spritecollide(player, bullets, True, pygame.sprite.collide_mask)

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

I managed to make an algorithm that looks at the corners of each rect:

```
def rectsCollideSimple (rect1, surf1, rect2, surf2):
    collide = False
    try:
        if surf1.get_at((rect2.left - rect1.left, rect2.top - rect1.top)) != surf1.get_colorkey():
            collide = True
    except IndexError:
        useless = None
    try:
        if surf1.get_at((rect2.right - rect1.left, rect2.top - rect1.top)) != surf1.get_colorkey():
            collide = True
    except IndexError:
        useless = None
    try:
        if surf1.get_at((rect2.left - rect1.left, rect2.bottom - rect1.top)) != surf1.get_colorkey():
            collide = True
    except IndexError:
        useless = None
    try:
        if surf1.get_at((rect2.right - rect1.left, rect2.bottom - rect1.top)) != surf1.get_colorkey():
            collide = True
    except IndexError:
        useless = None
    return collide

def rectsCollide (rect1, surf1, rect2, surf2):
    if rectsCollideSimple(rect1, surf1, rect2, surf2) or rectsCollideSimple(rect2, surf2, rect1, surf1):
        return True
    else:
        return False
```

Probably not the most effcient way, but it solved my problem :)